# Converting Lead to Contact Related Record Files are not attaching to Contact record

Tags: files, lead-conversion, after-trigger

While I'm Converting Lead to Contact, Related Lead Record Files are not attaching/updating to a Contact record. Only record data is updating to Contact but not files, please help me with this

```
public without sharing class LeadTriggerHelper {
    public LeadTriggerHelper() {
        System.debug('Inside LeadTriggerHelper Constructor');
    }

    public static void LeadAssign(List<Lead> leadList)
    {
        String userId  = UserInfo.getUserId();
        List<Lead> leadRecs= new List<Lead>();
        Map<String, String> clientNames_Ids = new Map<String, String>();
      
        //set<Id> leadIdSet = new set<Id>();
        for(Lead leadRecord : leadList) {
            if (leadRecord.Status == 'On boarding' && leadRecord.isConverted == false){//add a check for change in status value
               //leadRecord.Area_Name__c=leadRecord.Area__c;
                clientNames_Ids.put(leadRecord.Client_Name__c, null);
                leadRecs.add(leadRecord);
                //leadIdSet.add(leadRecord.Id);
            }
        } 
        
        for(Account clientAccount : [SELECT Id, Name 
                                      FROM  Account
                                      WHERE Name in :clientNames_Ids.keyset()
                                     ]){
                                         
            if(clientNames_Ids.containskey(clientAccount.Name))
                clientNames_Ids.put(clientAccount.Name, clientAccount.Id);
            
        }
       /* for(ContentDocumentLink objContent : [select Id,LinkedEntityId from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId IN : leadIdSet]){
            
        }*/
        
        
        LeadStatus CLeadStatus= [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus 
                                 WHERE  IsConverted=true];
        //List<Lead> acName = [Select Id, ConvertedAccountId, ConvertedContactId, IsConverted,Client_Name__c , ConvertedDate, Lead.ConvertedAccount.Name from Lead where IsConverted = true ];
        List<Database.LeadConvert> MassLeadconvert = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
        for(Lead currentlead : LeadRecs){
            Database.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
            Leadconvert.setOwnerId(userId);//owner id
            Leadconvert.setLeadId ( currentlead.Id); 
            Leadconvert.setAccountId(clientNames_Ids.get(currentlead.Client_Name__c));
            //Leadconvert.setContactId();

            Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus(CLeadStatus.MasterLabel);
            Leadconvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(TRUE); 
            //you can remove this line if you want to create an opportunity during  conversion 
            MassLeadconvert.add(Leadconvert);
        }
        
        if (!MassLeadconvert.isEmpty()) {
            List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(MassLeadconvert);
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you convert a Lead, some things happen automatically as per the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.faq_leads_what_happens_when.htm&type=5)

> When you convert a lead, Salesforce creates an account, contact, and optionally an opportunity, using information from the lead you’re converting.

> If the lead was also a campaign member, Salesforce associates the campaign member record with the new contact. The converted lead becomes a read-only record. If existing accounts and contacts share the names specified on the leads, you can choose to update the existing accounts and contacts.

> Salesforce adds information from the lead into empty fields; Salesforce doesn’t overwrite existing account and contact data.

> Salesforce attaches all activities from the converted lead to the resulting account, contact, and opportunity, except activities initiated from a High Velocity Sales cadence.

Note that `Files` are not auto-copied over to anywhere.  Your code will need to take the `ContentDocumentLinks` associated to the Lead and *clone* it to point at the converted-to-AccountId,ContactID, or OpportunityId based on business requirements.

Since your code is bulkified, you'll need a `Map<Id,ContentDocumentLink[]> contentDocumentLinksByLeadId` declared and exploited